# Hosting ASP.NET Web Forms as a Windows Azure Web Site

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms

I have a traditional ASP.NET Web Forms application. I would like to host the application in Windows Azure. Is it possible for me to publish a Web Forms app as a Web Site in Windows Azure? If so, does anyone have any docs? I can't seem to find any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Here is a great official tutorial : https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database

**EDIT:**

In my case I use [Team Foundation Service](https://tfs.visualstudio.com/) to [auto-deploy to Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/). It works great !

Comment: Has the provided link content changed? Because it guides on how to deploy ASP.NET MVC app in Azure, not Web Forms app?

Comment: That tutorial is for an MVC app and @YUI Developer asked about WebForms. I've heard there are concerns about managing Session State since Azure web apps are supposed to be stateless, which explains how its easy to scale them them out horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

This is new article because the link in accepted answer has been changed

***[another example](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-webforms-app-membership-oauth-sql-database.md)***

Answer (score 0):

@JYL's answer covers most of it, but also realize that WebForms apps are big on server side Session State. If you plan to scale out your web app, then you are going to need an external session state provider. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching) explains how you can do this with Redis Cache or SQL Server